# How to preserve mtime/ctime of a file while copying file from local to remote using ansible playbook?

Tags: bash, ansible, remote-access

I am trying to copy a script to a remote machine and I have to preserve `mtime` of the file.

I have tried using `mode:preserve` and `mode=preserve` as stated in ansible documentation, [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/copy_module.html)! 
but it seems to preserve permissions and ownership only.

```
- name: Transfer executable script script
  copy:
    src: /home/avinash/Downloads/freeradius.sh
    dest: /home/ssrnd09/ansible
    mode: preserve
```

Comment: apparently this module cant preserve the mtime. you could enhance your code to "grab" the file's mtime from machineA, and upon copying the file to machineB, modify its mtime using a shell task

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [`synchronize` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html), and its `times` and `rsync_opts` options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In respect to your question and the comment of [Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/), I've setup a test with [`synchronize`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html)_module and with parameter [`times`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html#parameter-times), which was working as required.

```
---
- hosts: test.example.com
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Synchronize passing in extra rsync options
    synchronize:
      src: test.sh
      dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/test.sh"
      times: yes
```

**Thanks to**

- [How to tell `rsync` to preserve time stamp on files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61586/)